# way to mastering web page in laravel

Tags: laravel, master-pages

i try to develop a website use laravel. but i someing confuse mastering templete. there are two type of page
    1. home page  2. category/menu page number 1 and number 2 type page header and footer page sameler, only 2 number page use a right sidebar. how to mastering the page stenderd way.. number 1 and number 2 page use only one @extends?

home page and menu page image https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF2Wv.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF2Wv.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can include views as well

```html
<div>
    @include('right-sidebar')
</div>
```

I recommend reading the docs first

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#including-sub-views